# Where to insert google map api key in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, google-maps

in my wordpress website i am getting this error for google map

**Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError**

now i have google map api key but i don't know where to insert it, i am not using google map plugin, i am using theme that contain build in google map, what i found now is the reference to google map javascript file that contain this code

```
 var tl_geocoder;var $tl_map;var $tl_marker=false;jQuery(function(a){jQuery(document).ready(function(c){tl_geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();c(document).on("click",".layers-check-address",function(f){f.preventDefault();$tl_map=c(this).closest(".layers-map");var g=c(this).closest(".layers-content").find('input[id$="google_maps_location"]').val();var d=c(this).closest(".layers-content").find('input[id$="google_maps_long_lat"]').val();$tl_map.data("location",g.toString());$tl_map.data("longlat",d.toString());b(c)});b(c)});function b(d){var c=false;jQuery(".layers-map").each(function(){var h=d(this);var k=(undefined!==h.data("longlat"))?h.data("longlat"):null;if(null!==k){var l=k.split(",");var m=l[0];var e=l[1]}else{var m="-34.397";var e="150.644"}var f=new google.maps.LatLng(m,e);var j=h.data("zoom-level");$tl_map=new google.maps.Map(h[0],{scrollwheel:false,zoom:j,center:f,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});var g=!d(this).closest("div.layers-contact-widget").hasClass("no-infobox");if(undefined!==h.data("longlat")){var n=new google.maps.LatLng(m,e);$tl_map.setCenter(f);$tl_marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:$tl_map,position:n,zIndex:google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX+1,icon:TL_CONF.themeurl+"/assets/images/google-marker.png"});if(!c&&g){c=true;d("body").trigger("setInfobox")}else{$tl_marker.setMap($tl_map)}}if(undefined!==h.data("location")&&$tl_marker===false){var i=h.data("location");tl_geocoder.geocode({address:i},function(p,o){if(o==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){$tl_map.setCenter((p[0].geometry.location?p[0].geometry.location:f));$tl_marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:$tl_map,zIndex:google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX+1,position:(p[0].geometry.location?p[0].geometry.location:f),icon:TL_CONF.themeurl+"/assets/images/google-marker.png"});if(!c&&g){c=true;d("body").trigger("setInfobox")}else{$tl_marker.setMap($tl_map)}}})}})}}(jQuery));
```

but i am still not sure where to insert google map api key

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Google maps introduced the api key usage as a recent update and the theme you're using has the older version of the api, one that does not use the api key.

You should check for an update of the theme. If it is an active one, the developer should have incorporated the api key mechanism by now so that you can provide the api key directly somewhere under the theme settings (in wp-admin).

If not, you can try with any of the available Google Maps plugins. I know for a fact that some such plugins work without an api key even today, e.g. the SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle ver. 1.6.1:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/so-widgets-bundle/developers/